# Css/Jquery Slide Up Panel

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I trying to make a slide up panel the reveals a hidden menu with css/jquery If you look at this link http://www.responsivefilemanager.com/filemanager/dialog.php you will notice that when you hover over the file, a hidden menu is revealed. Can someone give me an example as to how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/umquojyr/)

HTML

```
<br/><br/><br/>

<div class="container-two-div">
    <div class="contain-things back">
        Back
    </div>
    <div class="contain-things front">
        File
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container-two-div , .contain-things
{
    height:50px;
    max-height:50px;
    min-height:50px;
    overflow:visible;
    background-color:gray;
    width:100px;
}

.front
{
    position:relative;
    top:-50px;
    transition: all 1s; /* transition when the mouse over */
    background-color:red;
    color:white;
}

.container-two-div:hover .front
{
    top:-100px;
}
```

Comment: What's with the `</br>`? Why does your code start with three end tags?

Comment: Just for jsfiddle . because if i don't do that when the div slideup it will be out of the document and @tyrese moore will not see the demo correctly , so i added 3 </br> only for the demo

Comment: Come on, that would also work if you didn't introduce errors.

Comment: what errors ?   are you talking about

Comment: The `</br>` end tag. `br` elements don't even have end tags! If you think `</br>` is correct instead of `<br>`, I want to know where you learned that. It's an error! Run your code through the W3C Validator if you don't believe me.

Comment: My friend what i love about html it's an easy codding language . it allows the <br> </br> and <br/> . another thing a tag that does not have an ending can be an ending its self

Comment: Another thing i did discover today , google microsoft facebook and even the w3 validator it's self has ERRORS on it's own validator page i think you should not say stuff without testing

Comment: In XHTML, you can use `<br />`, and in HTML5, you can use `<br>`. Three closing break tags is invalid markup, even though you might find browsers to be tolerant enough to render them. @MrLister is quite correct here - may I suggest you update this answer?

Comment: @Diptox Even if there were errors on the validation page, that wouldn't mean it's wrong about everything. It says a `</br>` end tag is an error, and it's right! Sure, HTML "allows" errors, but that doesn't mean you should introduce errors deliberately!

Answer (score 0):

Try This.

http://jsfiddle.net/aqm7kjbg/2/

**HTML**

```
<div class="main">
 <div class ="samp1">
    Content
 </div>
 <div class="description">
    Description
 </div>
 <div class="icon">
    Icon
 </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main{
 width:100%;
 height:140px;  

}
.samp1{

 background-color:grey;
 padding:10px 10px 20px 10px;

}
.description{
 position:absolute;
 background-color:red;
 width:97.1%;
}
.icon{
 background-color:blue;

}
```

**JQUERY**

```
$('.main').hover(function(){
  $('.description').animate({'margin-top': '-18px'}, 500);
}, function(){
  $('.description').animate({'margin-top': '0px'}, 500);
})
```